# Set password to Microsoft Active Directory users when create a new User From Java Code

Tags: java, active-directory

I would like to set the Password of Active Directory User of Microsoft from the Java. Currently I am able to create the user but It is not storing the password for the same.
Used below code to set the password:

```
try
    {
        System.out.println("updating password...\n");
        String quotedPassword = "\"" + password + "\"";
        char unicodePwd[] = quotedPassword.toCharArray();
        byte pwdArray[] = new byte[unicodePwd.length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < unicodePwd.length; i++)
        {
        pwdArray[i * 2 + 1] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] >>> 8);
        pwdArray[i * 2 + 0] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] & 0xff);
        }
        System.out.print("encoded password: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < pwdArray.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.print(pwdArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
        mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("UnicodePwd", pwdArray));
        ldapContext.modifyAttributes("cn=" + username + BASE_NAME, mods);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("update password error: " + e);
    }
```

Please help me if is there any issue in above code. I am doing above things with SSL connection.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Not getting any error. but it is not updating as well. I have disable the firewall setting as well. but not set.

Comment: Now it is fine. We are using OpenLDAP now.